# Nginx proxy path return url is origin

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxy

Nginx works like a proxy for a couple of websites. On one of the sites there is redirect to SSO login and in return URL displayed origin domain and not the proxy one.

The conf:

```
location /demo/web1 {
proxy_pass https://website1.net/web1/index.html;
proxy_redirect default;
proxy_redirect https://website1.net/web1/index.html https://proxywebsites.com/demo/web1;
}

location /demo/monitor {
proxy_pass https://monitorwebsite.net/monitor;
proxy_redirect default;
proxy_redirect https://monitorwebsite.net/monitor https://proxywebsites.com/demo/monitor;
}

location /Home/SignIn {
proxy_pass https://thirdWebsite.net/Home/SignIn;
proxy_redirect default;
proxy_redirect https://thirdWebsite.net/Home/SignIn https://proxywebsites.com/Home/SignIn;
}
```

How it works? When you load the /demo/monitor, you will be redirected to /Home/SignIn, from there you will be redirected to SSO website, for example http://sso.com?id=blalba. The problem is that it redirects with "returnUrl" parameter and in that parameter return url is not the proxy on, but origin. For example:
http://sso.com?id=blalba&ReturnUrl=monitorwebsite.net/monitor and should be http://sso.com?id=blalba&ReturnUrl=proxywebsites.com/demo/monitor